# Src of an image with text + php variable

Tags: php, image, woocommerce, base64, base64url

Hey i am having a hard time getting this to work I used this [code](https://gist.github.com/cyberwani/ad5452b040001878d692c3165836ebff)

to upload images as base64 and then show them with the order details
everything is okay and the image is uploaded but I can't show the image uploaded

this is the function

```
/**
 * Add order item meta.
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'add_order_item_meta' , 10, 2);

function add_order_item_meta ( $item_id, $values ) {

    if ( isset( $values [ 'custom_data' ] ) ) {

      save_image($custom_data);
      $image =  " <img src='https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/ .$hashed_filename' >";

      wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Image', $image );
        
    }
}
```

After testing that the image only shows the link without the variable

as I saw on google, I need to add echo before the variable, but I can't because it will be saved in a variable for that function ($image)

Comment: what does ``hashed_filename`` represent?

Comment: and there's a ``dot .`` just before the ``$hashed_filename`` which I guess is of no use. Remove it as it doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: and in the function, where you are getting the value of ``$hashed_filename`` as I can see no source?

Comment: $hashed_filename is the name of the file uploaded and I tried removing the dot and nothing changed

Comment: ``$hashed_filename`` is null in the function ( doesn't have any value )

Comment: $hashed_filename is from save_image function, it's from here 
https://gist.github.com/cyberwani/ad5452b040001878d692c3165836ebff

Comment: that I see but from where you're passing the value in the function? It's empty.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
$image =  "<img src='https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/" . $hashed_filename . "'>";
```